# Vim function : how to expand vim variable in shell command?

Tags: vimscript, functions, ctags, shell, cscope

I'm trying to write a vim function to update `ctags` and `cscope` databases. I'm trying to save the vim variable `projectRoot` in environment variable then expand this enviroment variable in the `find` command. But it is not working. Here is my try:

```
let projectRoot="/mnt/hgfs/projects/myProject/"

function! UpdateTagDB()
   :cd /
   :execute("let ProRoot=".g:projectRoot)
   :find $ProRoot -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' > $ProRoot/cscope.files<cr>
   :execute("cd ".g:projectRoot)
   :!ctags -R .<cr>
   :!cscope -bR<cr>
endfunction

nnoremap <F5> :call UpdateTagDB()
```

When hitting `F5`, it gives me:

```
line 2:
E15: Invalid expression: /mnt/hgfs/projects/myProject/
line 3:
E345: Can't find file "$ProRoot -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' > $ProRoot/cscope.files<cr>" in path
```

What is missing and how to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:execute` command will assemble an Ex command from strings and evaluate it.

Here, in this case, it's actually *breaking* your command, since it's expanding the `g:projectRoot` string and forming a string that is an invalid Ex command, since the quotes around the path are now missing. That command is actually equivalent to:

```
let ProRoot=/mnt/hgfs/projects/myProject/
```

Just drop the `:execute` should be enough to fix it.

Also, to set an environment variable, you need to use the `$` prefix on the `let` command as well.

```
let $ProRoot = g:projectRoot
```

Finally, you don't need `:` anywhere inside a Vimscript function, it's all executed as Ex commands anyways. (The `:` doesn't break it, but it looks much nicer without it.)

Finally, your `find` is a shell command, so you need a `!` to have it executed by the shell.

There are a few more issues in the following lines, namely you shouldn't have `<CR>` at the end of commands, and you shouldn't have parents on the `:execute` for `cd` (parents denotes a function call, but this should be a command.)

Putting it all together:

```
function! UpdateTagDB()
    cd /
    let $ProRoot = g:projectRoot
    !find $ProRoot -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' > $ProRoot/cscope.files
    execute "cd ".g:projectRoot
    !ctags -R .
    !cscope -bR
endfunction
```

Finally, you *do* need a `<CR>` in your `:map` command. You probably also want to make it `<silent>` so it doesn't print the `:call` command on the command-line when executed:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F5> :call UpdateTagDB()<CR>
```

Comment: Many thanks for clarifying all these points.

Comment: One more point. When runnging the function, it displays three times `Press ENTER or type command to continue` in the command line. I have to hit `ENTER` three times to allow it to continue. Is there a way to get it to continue without hitting ENTER?

Comment: Yes, use `:silent` to suppress these. See `:help :silent` (and also `:help :!`). Remember you don't need the `:` here, so `silent !find ...` should be enough. Sometimes you might need `:silent!` with an extra `!`, but I think that's not really the case here, plain `:silent` should be enough.

Comment: It worked. Thank you